# C# - How do I get the URL of an icon from Steam Trading API (encoded)

Tags: c#, steam-web-api

Here is the part of the XML that the API returns for every item:

```
<message>
    <appid>730</appid>
    <classid>469467368</classid>
    <instanceid>302028390</instanceid>
    <currency>false</currency>
    <background_color/>
    <icon_url>
    -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpou6ryFA957PfMYTxW09SzlZaS2aX3MOvSlzlQucdy2LqU9NmnjAzl_UJoYmqldYSTIQI_NV_X81bvkufxxcjryPo2vmI
    </icon_url>
</message>
```

How do I parse and convert this string to an URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never used this Api. I searched on google and i came on this answer: [Steam Web API: I'm not sure what to do with this hash looking url to generate an image with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523210/steam-web-api-im-not-sure-what-to-do-with-this-hash-looking-url-to-generate-an). It seems you just need to prepend the http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/ before the url string.

The image link in your case should be: http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpou6ryFA957PfMYTxW09SzlZaS2aX3MOvSlzlQucdy2LqU9NmnjAzl_UJoYmqldYSTIQI_NV_X81bvkufxxcjryPo2vmI

Comment: Really? That easy? Thanks for help!

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the answer is really "under the nose" :)