# c# - HtmlAgilityPack Not pulling any data from webpage

Tags: c#, html, parsing, xpath

I am trying to write this script that pulls my stats from the steam api. I follow many other tutorials and based my code mostly on these posts: [Parsing HTML page with HtmlAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512562/parsing-html-page-with-htmlagilitypack) and [C# - How do I get the URL of an icon from Steam Trading API (encoded)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066161/c-sharp-how-do-i-get-the-url-of-an-icon-from-steam-trading-api-encoded) But when I run my project it just returns a blank screen, with no error codes or anything. Here's the source code:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace csgo_stats
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&steamid=76561197972495328");
            XPathNavigator docNav = doc.CreateNavigator();
            XPathNavigator stats = docNav.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/pre");
            Console.WriteLine(stats);
            Console.ReadKey(); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like your `XPathNavigator kills` variable is storing null or empty string, meaning your `docNav.SelectSingleNode(...)` query isn't returning any valid data.

Comment: If `1474` is the number of your actual kills, it is **not** inside a list element but rather in a paragraph: `/html/body/div[3]/main/section[1]/div/ul[1]/li[1]/div/p`

Comment: @jan I'll try that out and see if it works

Comment: @Jan , with that xpath you gave me it still returns a blank line

Comment: @BradenParks: What about: `//p[@class='current'][1]` ?

Comment: @Jan sorry no still just getting blank line

Comment: @ext0 do you know how I would be able to fix that?

Comment: @Jan I am trying a new site but still am having the same problem. Do you think you can help?

Comment: Off topic, but I'd strongly suggest using something like [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) or the (unfortunately no-longer-maintained) [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) instead of HtmlAgilityPack - they provide much simpler ways of querying the DOM, particularly if you're already familiar with libraries like jQuery.